# My listview doesn't show last item

Tags: android, listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/olaylar_liste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Last item is not showing. Please help.

Comment: post your listview holding xml

Comment: put `android:layout_height="match_parent" ` in listview

Comment: post item listView xml and full code  adapter

Comment: if you are using     android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout then you must have to use recycle view

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar and to parent of RecyclerView or to RecyclerView add in XML `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: check here is sample of all this https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/olaylar_liste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>


</LinearLayout>

Comment: Mehmet bey, please post your adapter and activity? There should be some padding programmatically or ads if you have?

Comment: Problem should be your view pager does not match with parent. Make sure it strecthes to screen properly.

Comment: I wrote android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   instead of LinearLayout Fix Problems. Thank you all.

Comment: @MehmetÖzay did you just change the linearLayout? Because I did the same but the last row always gets cut off

Answer (score 41):

Add this line to your Viewpager

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

because the size you don't have at bottom is exactly the size taken by your `ToolBar`,

which is supposed to be hide `(using new Android Design)` when you reach to bottom.

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: saved my day . Thanks

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` this line was what i needed thank you.

Answer (score 2):

as you see your device is a bit smaller than content of your `ListView`.

#### Solution 1.

Add `paddingBottom` with at least `20dp` value to your olaylar_liste `ListView`.

Try also if previous doesn't work, adding also `marginBottom="20dp"`.

#### Solution 2.

Try to implement `ScrollView` like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"> //THIS GUY would be useful

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/olaylar_liste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

  </ScrollView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Read also: [Working with the ScrollView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ScrollView)

Hope it help

Comment: ListView in ScroolView = bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ListView

        android:id="@+id/lv_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_listview"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            );
}
```

Comment: what this exactly means ?

Answer (score 0):

Add android:paddingBottom to ViewFlipper it works for me.

```
<ViewFlipper
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/fragment_workorder_list_viewFlipper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using tableview from de.codecrafters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vlad.zimmer.porProgramar$PlaceholderFragment">
    <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
        android:id="@+id/tableView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding this line, works for me like a charm:

android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding  android:layout_height="0dp" to my ListView and android:layout_height="wrap_content" to the parent ViewGroup of my ListView solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

you must set 
        android:paddingBottom="" in your list view or recyclerview.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_prod_category"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: You can't set a value "" to android:paddingBottom!

Comment: @Elenasys I know actually I wanted to say set a value for paddingBottom not empty value