# GridView cuts off last row

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `GridView` that I populate through code, the problem is that the last row it's not fully visible. I don't know why this is happening, the layout of the `Activity` is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/sectionGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Layout for the row is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:pew="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/sectionImage"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_section_row"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sectionTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:id="@+id/sectionBgView"></RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sectionImage"
            android:id="@+id/sectionTitle"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure if it might be related but currently i'm using the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

What's wrong with the layout? am I missing any property for the `GridView`?

Comment: In GridView  set padding ....android:paddingBottom="20dp"

Comment: @sasikumar I know that adding a padding works but I feel it's pretty hackish and it's not the solution I'd like to use

Comment: @Signo You mean when you loading dynamic data in `Grid View` it is not showing last row ?

Comment: @jaydroider the GridView gets populated correctly, but the last row is not fully visible, I cannot scroll the GridView till the end as it gets cut off

Comment: @Signo May be you can give padding right,left,bottom,top  `10 dp` is what i suggest you to apply.

Comment: @jaydroider I've tried with some padding and I can see the missing content of the cell, but I feel this is just a workaround to the real solution, I've tried lot of xml properties for both the GridView and LinearLayout but none of them worked :(

Comment: @Signo The properties preferable to solved this is padding mostly. so don't waste your time to do tricky solution.

Comment: @jaydroider but how can I know what's the correct padding for every device?

Comment: @Signo Okay then you can go through using `dimens.xml` for each `values` folder.

Comment: @jaydroider I got it working, the problem was related to a library, thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449336/my-listview-doesnt-show-last-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after wasting hours I found out this issue on the library i'm using in order to create a Sliding Menu:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680

I've added the following code to my BaseActivity (every activity inherits from this):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

And it did the trick. The problem seem to happen only on devices with API > 21

Answer (score 1):

In GridView **android:verticalSpacing** or **android:horizontalSpacing** only works if there is another cell to give spacing between.

Even for the first cell the spacing doesn't get applied in the top but as soon as second cell is drawn the verticalSpacing property works and a gap can be observed between the cell.

In this case, the bottom cell doesn't have any other cell to show below it as a result the last cell looks like being cut from bottom.

Try giving a padding for LinearLayout in row cell.
eg: **android:paddingBottom="5dp"**