# Gridview last items are not fully visible

Tags: android, gridview

I have made a gridview with one imageview.when i scroll gridview last row items are not fully visible. here is the screenshot in which last two photos are not fullt visible.[image]

here is my fragment.

```
package com.secretphotosandvideoslocker.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.secretphotosandvideoslocker.R;
import com.secretphotosandvideoslocker.adapters.PhotoAlumbAdapter;
import com.secretphotosandvideoslocker.interfaces.AllImagePath;
import com.secretphotosandvideoslocker.interfaces.SupportInterface;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment implements AllImagePath {

    private View myView;
    private GridView gridView;
    private int size;
    private PhotoAlumbAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> list = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, null);
        new SupportInterface(this);
        gridView = (GridView) myView.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
        int value = getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        orientationBasedUI(value);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });
        return myView;

    }

    private void orientationBasedUI(int orientation) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        size = orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? metrics.widthPixels / 3 : metrics.widthPixels / 5;
        gridView.setNumColumns(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? 3 : 5);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.secretphotosandvideoslocker/Images");
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                list.add(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            adapter = new PhotoAlumbAdapter(list, getActivity(), size);
        }
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAllImage() {
        int value = getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        orientationBasedUI(value);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml which is being used in this fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/photo_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is adapter for this gridview.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.secretphotosandvideoslocker.R;

import java.util.List;



public class PhotoAlumbAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private View myView;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<String> list;
    private Context context;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private int size;
    private DisplayImageOptions imageOptions;

    public PhotoAlumbAdapter(List<String> list, Context context, int size) {
        this.list = list;
        this.size = size;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).build();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View V, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        myView = V;
        if (V == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_grid_item, null);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            myView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) myView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.imageView.getLayoutParams().width = size;
        viewHolder.imageView.getLayoutParams().height = size;
        imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + list.get(position), viewHolder.imageView, imageOptions);
        return myView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change your gridview height to wrap_content

Comment: give padding to your relative layout. android:paddingBottom=15dp

Comment: I have already tried that @Anjali

Comment: This is not a perfect solution @AbhayBohra

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA Set to scrollToPosition to your last item of your list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319611/gridview-cuts-off-last-row check this link

Comment: This is not also working @Anjali.Give some other suggestion